# How to get element's object whose border is none using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following markup, where I need to get the element whose border is none. And I have a jQuery code  `var $item = $('[style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; border: medium none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 1px; align-self: stretch;"]');` which is hard coded in the following condition it solves the problem but the inline css of `class="item"` is generated dynamically which is impossible to find what style attribute has. So, how can I solve the this problem i.e how can I get those elements which do not have border.

```js
var $item = $('[style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; border: medium none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 1px; align-self: stretch;"]');

console.log($item.length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-wrp">
   <div class="item-wrp">
      <div class="item" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 1px; align-self: stretch;">
         <div class="cont1">
            <div class="img-wrp" style="display: block;">
            <a href="#">
            <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Uek.jpg" class=""></a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="cont2">
            <div class="news-cat-wrp">
            <span class="news-cat" style="color: rgb(157, 157, 157);"> Nationals</span>
            </div>
            <div class="news-tit-wrp">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(39, 39, 39);" class="news-tit">द भ्वाइस अफ नेपाल र हाम्रो पात्रोबीच सहकार्य</a></div>
            <div class="news-auth-wrp">
               <div class="news-auth">
                  <a class="news-auth-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
                     <span class="news-auth-name" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">John Deo</span>
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div data-title="Date" class="news-date-wrp">
            <span class="news-date" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">2018-09-06</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="cont3">
            <div class="news-sum-wrp">
            <span class="news-sum" style="color: rgb(40, 40, 40);">
            २१ भदाै, काठमाडौं । विश्वकै चर्चित गायन रियालिटी शो “द भ्वाइस” को नेपाली संस्करण (फ्रेञ्चाइज) द भ्वाइस अफ नेपाल र नेपालको सबैभन्दा बढी डाउनलोड भएको जीवनशैली एप हाम्रो पात्रोबीच पहिलो सिजनको एकापसी सहक...
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="news-btn-wrp">
            <a class="news-btn" style="text-decoration: none; border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); color: rgb(255, 36, 0);" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="item-wrp">
      <div class="item" style="width: 100%; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 0px; border: medium none; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 0px 2px 1px; align-self: stretch;">
         <div class="cont1">
            <div class="img-wrp" style="display: block;">
            <a href="#">
            <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Uek.jpg" class=""></a></div>
         </div>
         <div class="cont2">
            <div class="news-cat-wrp">
            <span class="news-cat" style="color: rgb(157, 157, 157);"> Nationals</span>
            </div>
            <div class="news-tit-wrp">
            <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(39, 39, 39);" class="news-tit">द भ्वाइस अफ नेपाल र हाम्रो पात्रोबीच सहकार्य</a></div>
            <div class="news-auth-wrp">
               <div class="news-auth">
                  <a class="news-auth-link" href="javascript:void(0);">
                     <span class="news-auth-name" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">John Deo</span>
                  </a>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div data-title="Date" class="news-date-wrp">
            <span class="news-date" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204);">2018-09-06</span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="cont3">
            <div class="news-sum-wrp">
            <span class="news-sum" style="color: rgb(40, 40, 40);">
            २१ भदाै, काठमाडौं । विश्वकै चर्चित गायन रियालिटी शो “द भ्वाइस” को नेपाली संस्करण (फ्रेञ्चाइज) द भ्वाइस अफ नेपाल र नेपालको सबैभन्दा बढी डाउनलोड भएको जीवनशैली एप हाम्रो पात्रोबीच पहिलो सिजनको एकापसी सहक...
            </span>
            </div>
            <div class="news-btn-wrp">
            <a class="news-btn" style="text-decoration: none; border-radius: 5px; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); color: rgb(255, 36, 0);" href="#">Read More</a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bad way of using jQuery to find objects. You should ideally be using a specific class/IDs on the items you want and then using that to select the element. eg: `$('.mySpecificClass')`.

But, if for some reason, the markup is built somewhere else and you still want to do it. This should suffice

```
$('.item[style]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('style').includes('border: none')
})
```

Not perfect by a long distance, but should work in your case. In case you're on an older browser, replace includes with [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: Hi @rmn thank you for your answer. Currently I have `border: medium none;` in style attribute it could be any thing I don't have control on style attribute. I need to get all those `item` element whose border are not visible.

Comment: When you say anything, I can't really write code for that, unless you can provide a list of different styles that can possibly come in the markup. One thing you can play around with and test in your own code base is with [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).